# How to fix "Choose an option" on Windows 10 boot?

Tags: boot, uefi, window

I followed some online tutorials for disabling Hyper-V, that went too far and called for `bcdedit` commands to modify the Windows bootloader. Now, every time I cold boot or hard restart my computer, I see this extra `Choose an option` menu instead of booting directly to Windows.

How can I fix this?

I tried some more `bcdedit` and `bootrec` commands to change this behavior, but the stupid `Choose an option` menu keeps displaying when hard restarting anyway.

The steps I tried:

https://gist.github.com/mcandre/c94222e52573c603ae740273577e2a2e

Comment: You would have to use bcdedit to remove the additional entries that exist.  What commands you have tried should be contained in the body of your answer.  I assume you can still access your installation, it just prompts you to select an entry, or are you unable to access your installation?

Comment: As I said, I already tried bcdedit. Here are the steps that I tried: https://gist.github.com/mcandre/c94222e52573c603ae740273577e2a2e